# openshift HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() threw exception

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, deployment, openshift, postman

I'm newbie for openshift , I developed a restful service project using netbeans and tomcat 7 and deployed it on openshift to use it in a small android project to learn some android stuff.
when I call the service from localhost using postman it returns the result , but when I call it from the openshift it returns this error **HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception**
putting in consideration that it returns the same index.html when I call the project link without the extension of the servlet and service "servlet mapping".

this returns the **http status 500**

**http://testandroid-anacondafci.rhcloud.com/AndroidBackEndTest2/services/getStudents/**

although this works
**http://localhost:8080/AndroidBackEndTest2/services/getStudents**

this is the web.xml file for the project
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
    <display-name>Testing</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>BackEndPackage</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

`

and this is the response form openshift

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1042)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: BackEndPackage/Services : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class BackEndPackage.Services)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2961)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$6.run(ReflectionHelper.java:374)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$6.run(ReflectionHelper.java:369)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:257)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:219)
    org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:1495)
    org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:169)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:883)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:840)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1171)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1140)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:299)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1042)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 logs.
```

thanks for interest

Answer (score 0):

The exception:

```
UnsupportedClassVersionError: BackEndPackage/Services : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

points to java version issues. If you build your app locally and then deploy to OpenShift, probably the Java version in OpenShift is older than the java version you compile your application with.

The major version 52 indicates that the code was compiled with Java 8. You can try compiling with Java 7 and deploying your application again.

If you use maven for your build, you can set source and target versions using: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html